# xlwings:copy a worksheet, and reproduce it at the end of an existing worksheet

Tags: python, copy, worksheet-function, xlwings

I'm useing xlwings on a Windows.

I copy a worksheet and want to reproduce it at the end of an existing worksheet now.
In a worksheet to copy, I use a photograph and the figure.

I know some sample code to reproduce copy a worksheet.

I would appreciate it if you could answer my questions.

Comment: What do you mean by "reprint"?

Comment: Thank you for your comment.I understood a word by mistake.I revised a question.I know some sample code to reproduce copy a worksheet.

Comment: This is not natively available yet, but you can work around like described here: https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/123

Comment: I'm Sorry,there was the same question.I have read your put link.I need After keyword so I have to wait until it's implemented.Thank you for telling me.

Comment: As written in the answer, the `After` parameter is implemented, it's just a little different to write. For example, `sheet.api.Copy(None, After=existingSheet.api)`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56687602/copy-excel-sheet-from-one-worksheet-to-another-in-python).

Answer (score 3):

The correct answer to copy a worksheet to the end of a workbook is to use the `After` parameter.

```
import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.Book("test.xlsx")
ws1 = wb.sheets['Sheet1']

ws1.api.Copy(None, After=wb.sheets[-1].api)
```

**Update 18. November 2021:**

Since xlwings version 0.22 you can use the built-in [`.copy()`](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html?highlight=copy#xlwings.Sheet.copy):

```
import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.Book("test.xlsx")
ws1 = wb.sheets['Sheet1']

ws1.copy(name="name_of_copied_sheet")
```

Comment: Worked for me. It places the new sheet at the very end. (right most position)

Answer (score 0):

I was settled with this code:

```
Sheet(1).xl_sheet.Copy(Before=Sheet(1).xl_sheet)
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from v0.10.4 replace xl_sheet with api:

```
Sheet(1).api.Copy(Before=Sheet(1).api)
```